# CakePhp Getting Entity 'raquo' not defined error when calling SOAP wdsl file

Tags: php, cakephp, soap, fedex

Im trying to connect to the FedEx PHP plugin, Ive successfully ran the plugin with my local Server. But when I try to run it on my CakePhp project I get the next error:

```
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://my-subdomain.mydomain.com/controller/wsdl' : Entity 'raquo' not defined
```

Using the url I can actually enter the wdsl page and see the file in XML file. I got a function and view which return this. This is that functions code:

```
public function wsdl() {
    $this->layout = false;
    $this->RequestHandler->respondAs('xml');
}
```

I can enter the url and see the correct display of the XML. Then when I try using the wsdl on my function which is in the same class I get the error above. This is the code I use to call the SOAP class:

```
    //The WSDL is not included with the sample code.
    //Please include and reference in $path_to_wsdl variable.
    $path_to_wsdl = "http://apibebe2go.bebe2go.com/home/wsdl";

    ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

    $client = new SoapClient($path_to_wsdl, array('trace' => 1));
```

I get and internal error from the CakePhp debug and the error above. Any ideas what I could try to make this work? If you guys need any more code Ill be happy to help :D

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved the problem another way. Not sure why the /wdsl file was not working when called via function to view, BUT I added the .wdsl file to the WebRoot file path I had and called the url from there. Now it works like it should. If you need further explanation on how I achieved this, feel free to ask here :D

Cheers! :P